# How to determine whether a three dimensional vector field is conservative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Does it have something to do with the partial derivatives of the vector field's components and equating them?

E.g: derivate i component for x, j for y, k for z, and seeing whether they equal each other?

Thanks and pardon my English :)

Comment: A vector field $f$ is conservative if its curl vanishes: $\nabla\times f=0$, so check that. For the notation, see [nabla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol).

Answer (score 0):

A vector field $f=f_{1}(x,y,z)i+f_{2}(x,y,z)j+f_{3}(x,y,z)k\,\,$ is

conservative if-f

$\bigtriangledown \times f=\begin{vmatrix}
 i& j & k \\
 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}& \frac{\partial }{\partial y} &\frac{\partial }{\partial z}  \\
 f_{1}(x,y,z)&f_{2}(x,y,z)  &f_{3}(x,y,z)  \\
\end{vmatrix}=0$

Comment: Not quite right! The “if” may fail.

Comment: It is if-f if U is an open connected set. But here we assume that curl is zero for all (x,y,z), that is U is the whole space. Therefore it is an if-f condition! See wikipedia!

Comment: No, you need simply connected! You should know the standard example.